# Segmentation Fault when running simple Ruby Twitter bot

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to write my own Twitter bot using Ruby and the [Twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) gem. When I run the program on my command line I get a Segmentation Fault error and apparently the JSON gem was to blame. I fixed it yesterday by removing and reinstalling Ruby using RVM. However today it's come back with a vengeance. After some googling today I rebuilt all my gems using `gem prestine --all`

When I ran my code again it's now telling me the `http_parser` gem is to blame, I've uninstalled it and reinstalled it but the problem persists.

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Here is the output from Terminal

```
/Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/lib/ruby_http_parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0021 p:-17538197654080 s:0105 e:000104 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0020 p:---- s:0103 e:000102 CFUNC  :require
c:0019 p:0196 s:0099 e:000098 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73
c:0018 p:0027 s:0089 e:000088 TOP    /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/lib/http_parser.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0017 p:---- s:0087 e:000086 CFUNC  :require
c:0016 p:0196 s:0083 e:000082 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73
c:0015 p:0007 s:0073 e:000072 TOP    /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/lib/http/parser.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0014 p:---- s:0071 e:000070 CFUNC  :require
c:0013 p:0196 s:0067 e:000066 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73
c:0012 p:0007 s:0057 e:000056 TOP    /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/streaming/connection.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0011 p:---- s:0055 e:000054 CFUNC  :require
c:0010 p:0196 s:0051 e:000050 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73
c:0009 p:0039 s:0041 e:000040 TOP    /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/streaming/client.rb:5 [FINISH]
c:0008 p:---- s:0039 e:000038 CFUNC  :require
c:0007 p:0196 s:0035 e:000034 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73
c:0006 p:0207 s:0025 e:000024 TOP    /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter.rb:26 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0023 e:000022 CFUNC  :require
c:0004 p:0073 s:0019 e:000018 RESCUE /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135
c:0003 p:0442 s:0016 e:000015 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144
c:0002 p:0007 s:0006 E:001788 EVAL   bot.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000bc8 TOP    [FINISH]

bot.rb:1:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
/Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
/Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/streaming/client.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
/Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/streaming/connection.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
/Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/lib/http/parser.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
/Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/lib/http_parser.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: bot.rb

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/rbconfig.rb
    4 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    5 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    6 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    8 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
    9 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   10 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   11 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
   15 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb
   16 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   17 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
   18 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   19 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   20 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/addressable-2.4.0/lib/addressable/version.rb
   21 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/addressable-2.4.0/lib/addressable/idna/pure.rb
   22 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/addressable-2.4.0/lib/addressable/idna.rb
   23 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/addressable-2.4.0/lib/addressable/uri.rb
   24 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe/version.rb
   25 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/delegate.rb
   26 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe/synchronized_delegator.rb
   27 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe.rb
   28 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/memoizable-0.4.2/lib/memoizable/instance_methods.rb
   29 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/memoizable-0.4.2/lib/memoizable/method_builder.rb
   30 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/memoizable-0.4.2/lib/memoizable/module_methods.rb
   31 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/memoizable-0.4.2/lib/memoizable/memory.rb
   32 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/memoizable-0.4.2/lib/memoizable/version.rb
   33 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/memoizable-0.4.2/lib/memoizable.rb
   34 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb
   35 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/version.rb
   36 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/basic_object.rb
   37 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/conversions.rb
   38 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/null_class_builder.rb
   39 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/null_class_builder/command.rb
   40 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/null_class_builder/commands/define_explicit_conversions.rb
   41 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/null_class_builder/commands/define_implicit_conversions.rb
   42 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/null_class_builder/commands/pebble.rb
   43 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/null_class_builder/commands/predicates_return.rb
   44 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/null_class_builder/commands/singleton.rb
   45 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/null_class_builder/commands/traceable.rb
   46 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/null_class_builder/commands/mimic.rb
   47 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/null_class_builder/commands/impersonate.rb
   48 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught/null_class_builder/commands.rb
   49 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/naught-1.1.0/lib/naught.rb
   50 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/null_object.rb
   51 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/utils.rb
   52 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/base.rb
   53 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe/non_concurrent_cache_backend.rb
   54 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe/mri_cache_backend.rb
   55 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe/cache.rb
   56 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/configuration.rb
   57 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/enumerable.rb
   58 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/core.rb
   59 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/util.rb
   60 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/cookie.rb
   61 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi.rb
   62 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb
   63 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb
   64 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/utils.rb
   65 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb
   66 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb
   67 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb
   68 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/parameters.rb
   69 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/middleware.rb
   70 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter.rb
   71 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/request.rb
   72 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/response.rb
   73 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/multipart-post-2.0.0/lib/composite_io.rb
   74 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/multipart-post-2.0.0/lib/parts.rb
   75 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/stringio.bundle
   76 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/upload_io.rb
   77 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/error.rb
   78 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/autoload.rb
   79 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb
   80 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/version.rb
   81 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/ostruct.rb
   82 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/generic_object.rb
   83 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb
   84 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/enc/utf_16be.bundle
   85 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/enc/utf_16le.bundle
   86 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/enc/utf_32be.bundle
   87 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/enc/utf_32le.bundle
   88 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
   89 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/generator.bundle
   90 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext.rb
   91 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json.rb
   92 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rate_limit.rb
   93 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/error.rb
   94 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/base64.rb
   95 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/digest.bundle
   96 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/digest.rb
   97 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/openssl.bundle
   98 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/bn.rb
   99 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/cipher.rb
  100 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/config.rb
  101 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/digest.rb
  102 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/x509.rb
  103 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb
  104 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/fcntl.bundle
  105 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/ssl.rb
  106 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl.rb
  107 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb
  108 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb
  109 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ftp.rb
  110 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/http.rb
  111 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/https.rb
  112 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldap.rb
  113 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldaps.rb
  114 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/mailto.rb
  115 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri.rb
  116 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb
  117 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth.rb
  118 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/headers.rb
  119 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/request.rb
  120 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/cursor.rb
  121 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/date_core.bundle
  122 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date/format.rb
  123 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date.rb
  124 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/time.rb
  125 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/creatable.rb
  126 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/entity.rb
  127 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/entity/hashtag.rb
  128 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/entity/symbol.rb
  129 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/entity/uri.rb
  130 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/entity/user_mention.rb
  131 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/factory.rb
  132 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/equalizer-0.0.10/lib/equalizer.rb
  133 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/identity.rb
  134 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/variant.rb
  135 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/media/video_info.rb
  136 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/media/video.rb
  137 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/media/animated_gif.rb
  138 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/media/photo.rb
  139 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/media_factory.rb
  140 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/entities.rb
  141 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/direct_message.rb
  142 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/geo.rb
  143 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/geo/point.rb
  144 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/geo/polygon.rb
  145 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/geo_factory.rb
  146 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/language.rb
  147 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/list.rb
  148 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/metadata.rb
  149 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/oembed.rb
  150 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/place.rb
  151 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/profile_banner.rb
  152 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/relationship.rb
  153 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb
  154 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb
  155 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/version.rb
  156 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/client.rb
  157 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/arguments.rb
  158 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/basic_user.rb
  159 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/profile.rb
  160 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/user.rb
  161 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb
  162 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/direct_messages.rb
  163 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/tweet.rb
  164 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/favorites.rb
  165 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/friends_and_followers.rb
  166 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/help.rb
  167 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/lists.rb
  168 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/media.rb
  169 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/response/parse_json.rb
  170 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/response/parse_error_json.rb
  171 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/token.rb
  172 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/oauth.rb
  173 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/geo_results.rb
  174 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/places_and_geo.rb
  175 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/saved_search.rb
  176 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/saved_searches.rb
  177 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/search_results.rb
  178 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/search.rb
  179 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/spam_reporting.rb
  180 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/suggestion.rb
  181 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/suggested_users.rb
  182 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/timelines.rb
  183 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/trend_results.rb
  184 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/trends.rb
  185 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/tweets.rb
  186 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/undocumented.rb
  187 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/settings.rb
  188 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/users.rb
  189 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/api.rb
  190 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/request/multipart_with_file.rb
  191 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/response/raise_error.rb
  192 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/client.rb
  193 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/size.rb
  194 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/source_user.rb
  195 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http-1.0.4/lib/http/errors.rb
  196 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http-1.0.4/lib/http/headers/mixin.rb
  197 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http-1.0.4/lib/http/headers/known.rb
  198 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http-1.0.4/lib/http/headers.rb
  199 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http-1.0.4/lib/http/request/writer.rb
  200 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http-1.0.4/lib/http/version.rb
  201 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http-1.0.4/lib/http/uri.rb
  202 /Users/Skip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/http-1.0.4/lib/http/request.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: can you provide the exactly line of your program that raises this exception?

Comment: If you're getting a hard crash it's either the fault of Ruby or a gem with C extensions. Does this manifest in the latest version Ruby 2.3.0?

Comment: @amalrikmaiait the output doesn't tell me which line, it's as soon as I run it in Terminal.

Comment: It looks like you're using both the built-in Ruby and RVM's managed Ruby, which shouldn't happen. Please add the output of `gem env` and `rvm info` to your question by copying/pasting the output into the question and formatting it appropriately. It's not necessary or desirable to add "Edit" or "Update" tags to the question at that point, simply insert the information where you would have put it if you'd added it initially.

Comment: @tadman updated to 2.3.0 and it's fixed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: This looks like the usual RVM problem. You're using 2.0.0 but the gems with extension libraries (`*.bundle`) were compiled against 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to Ruby 2.3.0 as per tadman's comment (I was using 2.0.0 before) and fixed a few errors that RVM warned me about, then made sure my system was using RVMs update to date version. Works fine now.